# Where does electrify acquire node from?

Tags: meteor, electron

When I use "electrify" and "electrify package", mongo and node are acquired from somewhere and packed into the electrified app. Where do they come from? Are these the mongo and node from meteor? Or the ones installed on the system? Do both the above commands use the same mongo and node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR: Your `~/.meteor` folder is where it is sourced from.

---

Searching the [GitHub Electrify repository](https://github.com/arboleya/electrify/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=mongo), we can see that the `MongoDB` path and daemon location is referenced in [this file](https://github.com/arboleya/electrify/blob/94bb01d72d1cc0cc041836514de628d2c9009c23/lib/env.js#L125) as `this.meteor.mongo` and `this.meteor.mongod`:

```
this.meteor.mongo  = join(this.meteor.dev_bundle, 'mongodb', 'bin', 'mongo');
this.meteor.mongod = join(this.meteor.dev_bundle, 'mongodb', 'bin', 'mongod');
```

Unwinding through those variables:

```
// https://github.com/arboleya/electrify/blob/94bb01d72d1cc0cc041836514de628d2c9009c23/lib/env.js#L114
this.meteor.dev_bundle     = join(this.meteor.tools, 'dev_bundle');

// https://github.com/arboleya/electrify/blob/94bb01d72d1cc0cc041836514de628d2c9009c23/lib/env.js#L113
this.meteor.tools          = this.meteor.root.replace(/meteor(\.bat)?$/m, '');

// https://github.com/arboleya/electrify/blob/94bb01d72d1cc0cc041836514de628d2c9009c23/lib/env.js#L112
this.meteor.root           = join(meteor_dir, meteor_symlink);

// https://github.com/arboleya/electrify/blob/94bb01d72d1cc0cc041836514de628d2c9009c23/lib/env.js#L109
meteor_symlink = fs.readlinkSync(join(meteor_dir, 'meteor'));

// https://github.com/arboleya/electrify/blob/94bb01d72d1cc0cc041836514de628d2c9009c23/lib/env.js#L108
meteor_dir    = join(this.os.home, '.meteor');
```

So, we can see that for Linux, it would be:

- `meteor_dir`: the home path (`~`), then the subfolder `.meteor`,

  - For me that is `~/.meteor`;
- `meteor_symlink`: follows the symlink of `meteor`,

  - For me, that links to `./packages/meteor-tool/1.3.5_1/mt-os.linux.x86_64/meteor`;
- `meteor_root`: the combination of the above (e.g., `~/.meteor/<symlink>`),

  - For me that is `~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/1.3.5_1/mt-os.linux.x86_64/meteor`;
- `meteor_tools`: `meteor_root`, minus the trailing "meteor",

  - For me that is `~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/1.3.5_1/mt-os.linux.x86_64/`;
- `meteor_dev_bundle`: `meteor_tools` then the subfolder `dev_bundle`,

  - For me that is `~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/1.3.5_1/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle`;
- `this.meteor.mongo`: `meteor_dev_bundle` then the subfolder `mongo` and then the subfolder `bin` and then the subfolder `mongo`

  - For me that is `~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/1.3.5_1/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/mongodb/bin/mongo`;
- `this.meteor.mongod`: equivalent to `this.meteor.mongo` with an appended `d` (i.e., `mongo` becomes `mongod`),

  - For me that is `~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/1.3.5_1/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/mongodb/bin/mongod`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this comprehensive answer. But for some reason unknown to me, the moment I use the command "electrify package" (as opposed to "electrify"), the node and mongo versions packaged therein are the ones on my system and not the ones inside the meteor packages. This is most likely related to electron-packager, I presume?